# Sharing an int or an integer object between multiple threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, algorithm, concurrency

I have a multithreaded program that includes data structures like `ConcurrentHashMap` and `ConcurrentLinkedList`, however I also need every thread to access a shared integer value. The threads themselves are custom thread classes I've made that extend class `Thread`. My two concerns here are:

- How can I make each thread see the same integer value? I don't think a primitive int would work as it would not be "passed by reference" (or rather passed by value of the object pointer). The integer needs to be mutable and any changes to one integer by a thread needs to be seen by all the other threads. Would using an Integer Object fix this, what about `AtomicInteger`?
- What should I use to preserve thread safety? Each thread will check the integer everytime a loop in them runs but it will change the integer when a thread has finished it's task and is about to return.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Aioobe's answer is the correct one, but consider their follow up.  Other libraries/APIs have been written to solve common problems you may experience through concurrent programming.

Comment: As all of the answers have said, yes, you can use AtomicInteger.  You also can simply use a `volatile int` field;  the very purpose of `volatile` is to make changes to a field's value immediately visible to other threads.

Comment: "Passed by reference?"  You can't _pass_ anything between threads.  There is nothing that prevents two threads from using the same `int` _variable_ though.  It could be a `static` variable, or it could be an instance variable of any object that is known to both threads.

Comment: All of the suggestions to use `AtomicInteger` assume that you want to perform some _atomic operation_ on it (e.g., an increment or a CAS), but "check the integer everytime a loop...runs" and "change the integer when a thread has finished it's task" do not sound very atomic to me.  What do the threads "check" the variable for?  How do they "change" it?  Most importantly, how will you insure that the "checks" and the "changes" are synchronized in some meaningful way?

Comment: - Would using volatile mean that each thread object sees the same int then? And if one changes one it affects how all of them see it?

Comment: -The threads I use are a separate class that extends thread, if this thread were to use any data structures from the main thread don't they need to be passed as parameters when the thread is constructed?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use an [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html).

I would however consider `AtomicInteger` as a fairly low level primitive. I would question the design. Have you considered using `ExecutorService`, `Callable`, `Futures`, `Semaphore`, `CountDownLatch`, the [Fork/Join](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/forkjoin.html) framework or other classes from the high level `java.util.concurrent` API?

Comment: volatile int will work fine for something like "flag", but even "x++" won't work reliably without synchronization. AtomicInteger is a way to go for those cases.

Comment: man I don't even know what half of those things mean lol! Thank you very much though, but this isn't like a full blown concurrent program or something, just this algorithm has to be concurrent; it's a BFS algorithm, with different threads working on the same graph at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AtomicInteger](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) . It supports many atomic operation. For e.g. `addAndGet`, `decrementAndGet`, etc. AtomicInteger does extend Number , so you can pass it to methods that operate on numerically based classes.

Answer (score 1):

Use an `AtomicInteger`. I suggest you to make it final and then use operations on the AtomicInteger such as `incrementAndGet`

Comment: Making AtomicInteger final won't make it immutable or something right? Like, AtomicInteger is an object not a primitive type?

Comment: Making the object final will guarantee that it is initialized only once. It is not a primitive type so you'll be able to change its contained field `value` by calling methods on the `AtomicInteger` object